# background picture for textview

Tags: android, background, textview, nine-patch

I have a textview and a nine-patch image. Assigning this image in the xml editor to the tag "background" works as desired. Now I want to set this image dynamically in the coding, I thought

```
myTextView.setBackgroundDrawable(mydrawable);
```

would be the right thing to do. My png is in res/drawable. The API says that mydrawable needs to be an object of type drawable

```
 R.drawable.myninepatch
```

is of type int. So my problem is that I have to convert from that int to a drawable somehow. Then I thought I can use a constructor

```
NinePatchDrawable mydrawable = new NinePatchDrawable();
```

But I am again not able to construct such an object. Anyone an idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [setBackgroundResource()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29), not setBackgroundDrawable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem, and I've used your answer but didn't work. I solved it using the draw 9 patch padding pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image)`

Comment: Try and explain your answer rather than just posting a line of code.